# Join lines from file using linux

Tags: linux, file, sed, grep, concatenation

I was looking for something like this. 
I have an demo.txt file which contains words a follows

```
bold
code
make
links
placing
line
return
```

where I'm willing to achieve the result as

```
bold
code
make
links
placing
line
return
bold code
code make
make links
links placing
placing line
line return
bold code make
code make links
make links placing
links placing line
placing line return
```

sed or awk or scripts can be helpful

Comment: interesting stuff , i am a bit curious .... what actually are you trying to do ?

Comment: Where do you want end. Should this go on like `bold code make links` ...?

Answer (score 2):

```
words_per_line() {
    local n=$(($1-1)) i j
    for ((i=0; i<${#words[@]}-n; i++)); do
        for ((j=0; j<=n; j++)); do
            printf "%s " ${words[i+j]}
        done
        echo
    done 
}

mapfile -t words < demo.txt     # read the file into a zero-indexed array

words_per_line 1
words_per_line 2
words_per_line 3
```

outputs

```
bold 
code 
make 
links 
placing 
line 
return 
bold code 
code make 
make links 
links placing 
placing line 
line return 
bold code make 
code make links 
make links placing 
links placing line 
placing line return
```

This produces the same output:

```
ruby -e '1.upto(3) {|n| ARGV.each_cons(n) {|a| puts a.join(" ")}}' $(< demo.txt)
```